# How to hide this Textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created Some Dives and I want To when User Click On `<span class="rp-r" style=""><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></span>` This Text area `<textarea id="text6" class="reply" name="reply" placeholder="Type Your Reply Here"></textarea>`  Hide.

```html
<div class="reply-cm" style="display: block;">
    <textarea id="text6" class="reply" name="reply" placeholder="Type Your Reply Here"></textarea>
    <button onclick="reply(6)" class="btn">Reply</button>
    <div id="reply6">
         <div class="replyes">
             <span class="rp-r" style="">Hide</span>
         </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: no, I have an loop in php and I have more one have this class I need Use Selector.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

use javascript

```
  <script>
     function hide_rpr(y) {

            var x = document.getElementById(y);

                x.style.display = 'none';
        }
   </script>
```

then

```
 <span class="rp-r" onclick="hide_rpr(<?php echo $idexample ?>)" style="">Hide</span>
```

Comment: no, I have an loop in php and I have more one have this class I need Use Selector.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="reply-cm" style="display: block;">
  <textarea id="text6" class="reply" name="reply" placeholder="Type Your Reply Here"></textarea> 
 <button onclick="reply(6)" class="btn">Reply</button>
     <div id="reply6">
           <div class="replyes">
           <span class="rp-r" style="" onclick="document.getElementById('text6').style.display='none'">Hide</span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ec7kdLvu/)

```
document.getElementById('hide').onclick = function hideStuff() {
    if(document.getElementById('text6').style.display == 'none'){
        document.getElementById('text6').style.display = '';
        document.getElementById('hide').innerHTML = "Hide";
     } else {
        document.getElementById('text6').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('hide').innerHTML = "Show";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best to hide the element via a CSS class. If you do that, you can hide it any way you wish. With `display:none`,`position:absolute; left:-10000px;` (not recommended), `visibility:hidden`...

If you directly manipulate inline styles as other answers suggest, your layout would depend on JavaScript, which is bad in my opinion. I think it's best if JavaScript handles logic and CSS handles styles.

---

This code searches for all elements with class `reply-cm` and finds all elements with class `js-hide` *inside* of them. Then, it adds a `click` event listener to all `js-hide` elements in which they hide their respective `reply-cm` elements.

```js
function bindHide(target, trigger) {
  trigger.addEventListener("click", function () {
    target.classList.add("is-hidden");
  });
}

function bindHideEvents() {
  var replies = document.getElementsByClassName("reply-cm");

  for (var i = 0; i < replies.length; i++) {
    var buttons = replies[i].getElementsByClassName("js-hide");

    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < buttons.length; i2++) {
      bindHide(replies[i], buttons[i]);
    }
  }
}

bindHideEvents();
```

```css
.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="reply-cm">
    <textarea id="text6" class="reply" name="reply" placeholder="Type Your Reply Here"></textarea>
    <button onclick="reply(6)" class="btn">Reply</button>
    <div id="reply6">
         <div class="replyes">
             <span class="rp-r js-hide">Hide</span>
         </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Here's a solution with [jQuery](https://jquery.com/):

```js
$(".js-hide").click(function (e) {
  $(this).closest(".reply-cm").addClass("is-hidden");
});
```

```css
.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="reply-cm">
    <textarea id="text6" class="reply" name="reply" placeholder="Type Your Reply Here"></textarea>
    <button onclick="reply(6)" class="btn">Reply</button>
    <div id="reply6">
         <div class="replyes">
             <span class="rp-r js-hide">Hide</span>
         </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```